# Electric Generator vs Electricity generator

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, noun-phrases

> I have just bought an ***Electric Generator /  Electricity generator***. It works very well.

Sometimes, I'm confused when using a noun with adjective or two nouns together. Please help me to distinguish them clearly

Comment: Electricity is a noun and usually used for physical contexts about fundamental particles, e.g., electron. Electric, however, is also an adjective and is used to describe things related to electrical energy

Answer (score 1):

Normally in English only proper nouns (names) are capitalised. In normal text it would be written:

> electric generator / electricity generator

So in my view, neither are correct.

However, if you are asking about choosing electric versus electricity then the second is a better description. It generates electricity; it is an electricity generator. However often such words are contracted and it is often found more convenient to write electric generator, which is symmetric with electric motor.
An electric motor *uses* electricity and cannot be called an electricity motor! The ambiguity only exists on your example (with a generator).

Other words that we might find used with electricity are:

> electricity meter, electricity company, electricity bill, electricity plant

These all relate to the supply of electricity, but all may often be shortened to electric.

Comment: At least in the US, the word _electric_ often gets used this way, where "electricity" might seem like a more logical adjective choice. This is common AmE parlance: _The electric company reads our electric meter and then sends us an electric bill, so that they can keep running their electric plant_.

Comment: @BrianTompsett What does the last line mean? Does it mean that regarding other items such as electric mortors, there's a set rule to use 'electric' or 'electricity', but only generators can be called either way to refer to the same thing? Sorry...

Comment: @Miki I would never expect to hear *electricity motor* was what I was suggesting

Comment: @BrianTompsett Thank you for taking your time to make my question clear :) ！

Comment: @BrianTompsett My apology for being persistent, but does this mean there are more items that are called both electricity something and electric something and they both refer to the same items?

Comment: @Miki As J.R. Indicated you could have electricity meter, electricity company, electricity bill and electricity plant all of which can be shortened to electric. The word electricity is used when related to the supply of electricity.